# Issue with arrays in Swift Library - Realm 2.4.1

Tags: arrays, swift, object, realm

I have a strange problem with the Realm Data Library.

Is it not possible to pull the data from the object that is in the array of realm data?

When you make simple object, like this one :

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Dog: Object {
var index = 0
var day = ""

}
```

After that, you make a list of objects with current type :

```
    var dog1 = Dog()
    var dog2 = Dog()
    var dog3 = Dog()

    dog1.day = "one day"
    dog1.index = 0

    dog2.day = "two day"
    dog2.index = 1

    dog3.day = "three day"
    dog3.index = 2


    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(dog1)
        realm.add(dog2)
        realm.add(dog3)
    }
```

Then, you get a list of those objects but from Realm, you couldn't take data from those objects.

Let's see...

```
    var dogs = realm.objects(Dog.self)
```

//Get list of created objects from realm

```
    print("All Dogs",dogs)
```

//Output :

```
    All Dogs Results<Dog> (
    [0] Dog {
    index = 0;
    day = one day;
    },
    [1] Dog {
    index = 1;
    day = two day;
    },
    [2] Dog {
    index = 2;
    day = three day;        
    })
```

//All is ok
//Next  3 commands and three outputs after

```
    print("Dog 1",dogs[0])


    print("Dog 2",dogs[1])


    print("Dog 3",dogs[2])
```

//Three outputs
//Output 1

```
    Dog 1 Dog {
       index = 0;
       day = one day;
    }
```

//Output 2

```
    Dog 2 Dog {
    index = 1;
    day = two day;
    }
```

//Output 3

```
    Dog 3 Dog {
    index = 2;
    day = three day;
    }
```

//Upper is all ok, but now problems starts

```
    print("Dog 1 day : ",dogs[0].day)
```

//Output

```
      Dog 1 day :
```

//Next

```
    print("Dog 2 day : ",dogs[1].day)
```

//Output:

```
    Dog 2 day :
```

//Next

```
    print("Dog 3 day : ",dogs[2].day)
```

//Output

```
    Dog 3 day :
```

//Ok in upper three commands all is bad

//Let's try another way

```
    print("Dog 1 day : ", realm.objects(Dog.self).first?.day)
```

//Output

```
    Dog 1 day :  Optional("")
```

//This way also didn't gave to me anything good

//And last way to see on this problem :

```
    let dogss = try! Realm().objects(Dog.self)
    for i in 0..<2 {
        let dog = dogss[i]
        print("Dog : ", dog,"\n\n\n\n")
        print("And just dog day : ", dog.day)
        // ...
    }
```

//Expected output:

```
    Dog :  Dog {
    index = 0;
    day = one day;
    } 
    And just dog day : one day  
    Dog :  Dog {
    index = 1;
    day = two day;
    } 

    And just dog day : two day
```

//But we have

```
   Dog :  Dog {
   index = 0;
   day = one day;
   } 
   And just dog day :  
   Dog :  Dog {
   index = 1;
   day = two day;
   } 
   And just dog day :
```

Afterwords:

So, i use  Xcode 8.2.1, swift 3. This is happening in all simulators.
I understand that perhaps it's my fault, so I'll be glad if you can help me solve this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties of built-in types (strings, integers, etc.) must be declared with the `dynamic` modifier to make it possible for Realm Swift to provide getters that retrieve values from the underlying Realm file. Without the `dynamic` modifier, the Swift compiler generates access to the underlying instance variable, which does not contain any data for objects loaded from a Realm file.